# Can you collect a list of posts a user has liked and/or commented on in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Using the graph API or FQL, is it possible to collect a list of posts an OAuthed user has liked and/or commented on?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no way to do this. The [`like`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/) FQL table looks promising at first but is not indexable on `user_id`, so it looks like you'll have to know what objects you want to check before you can do this.

Edit: Additionally, `/me/likes` only shows Facebook Pages and objects on Facebook.com, not for your domain or the Internet at large like I assume you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

By [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/og.likes), you can use `og.likes`. In Graph API, you can get your likes by using `/me/og.likes`.